# C++ use of deleted function on GCC but not on MSVC

Tags: c++, gcc, boost

The following compiles on msvc and not on gcc. Why?

game_tracker.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.hpp"
#include "game_tracker.hpp"
#include "basic_game_server.hpp"
#include "basic_session.hpp"
#include "api_session.hpp"
#include "protocols.hpp"

using namespace boost::asio;
using namespace std;

namespace games_zone{

    game_tracker::game_tracker(unsigned short port) : tracker_(io_service(thread::hardware_concurrency())),
        api_(io_service(thread::hardware_concurrency())),
        acceptor_(api_, ip::tcp::endpoint(ip::tcp::v4(), port), false),
        socket_(api_)
    {
        tracker_work_ = new boost::asio::io_service::work(tracker_);
        api_work_ = new boost::asio::io_service::work(api_);

        protocols::hl_game_server gs(boost::asio::ip::address_v4::from_string("89.44.246.184"), 27015);
        add(gs);
    }

    ...
}
```

game_tracker.hpp:

```
#pragma once

#include "basic_game_server.hpp"

namespace games_zone{
    class game_tracker :
        private boost::noncopyable
    {
    public:
        game_tracker(unsigned short);
        ~game_tracker();
        void run();
    private:
        boost::asio::io_service tracker_;
        boost::asio::io_service api_;
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket_;
        boost::asio::io_service::work* tracker_work_;
        boost::asio::io_service::work* api_work_;
        std::vector<basic_game_server*> servers_;

        void add(basic_game_server&);
        void do_accept();
    };
}
```

gcc error:

```
root@ubuntu:~/gz_tracker/build# make
Scanning dependencies of target gz_tracker
[ 16%] Building CXX object games_zone/CMakeFiles/gz_tracker.dir/game_tracker.cpp.o
/root/gz_tracker/games_zone/game_tracker.cpp: In constructor ‘games_zone::game_tracker::game_tracker(short unsigned int)’:
/root/gz_tracker/games_zone/game_tracker.cpp:16:15: error: use of deleted function ‘boost::asio::io_service::io_service(const boost::asio::io_service&)’
   socket_(api_)
               ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_io_object.hpp:19:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_socket.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_datagram_socket.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio.hpp:21,
                 from /root/gz_tracker/games_zone/stdafx.hpp:10,
                 from /root/gz_tracker/games_zone/game_tracker.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/io_service.hpp:185:7: note: ‘boost::asio::io_service::io_service(const boost::asio::io_service&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 class io_service
       ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/io_service.hpp:23:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_io_object.hpp:19,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_socket.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_datagram_socket.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio.hpp:21,
                 from /root/gz_tracker/games_zone/stdafx.hpp:10,
                 from /root/gz_tracker/games_zone/game_tracker.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/noncopyable.hpp:32:3: error: ‘boost::asio::detail::noncopyable::noncopyable(const boost::asio::detail::noncopyable&)’ is private
   noncopyable(const noncopyable&);
   ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_io_object.hpp:19:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_socket.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_datagram_socket.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio.hpp:21,
                 from /root/gz_tracker/games_zone/stdafx.hpp:10,
                 from /root/gz_tracker/games_zone/game_tracker.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/io_service.hpp:185:7: error: within this context
 class io_service
       ^
/root/gz_tracker/games_zone/game_tracker.cpp:16:15: error: use of deleted function ‘boost::asio::io_service::io_service(const boost::asio::io_service&)’
   socket_(api_)
               ^
make[2]: *** [games_zone/CMakeFiles/gz_tracker.dir/game_tracker.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [games_zone/CMakeFiles/gz_tracker.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I use boost 1.55 (current release) and compiled and run on Microsoft Visual Studio 2013.
I understand from this error that `api_` cannot bind to `explicit basic_stream_socket(boost::asio::io_service & io_service);`

What am I wrong? Is this a GCC bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In these two lines:

```
tracker_(io_service(thread::hardware_concurrency())),
api_(io_service(thread::hardware_concurrency())),
```

you're creating a temporary `io_service` and copying it into your member variables (which is not allowed because the copy constructor is private).

Try just

```
tracker_(thread::hardware_concurrency()),
api_(thread::hardware_concurrency()),
```

Comment: Thank you. Am I right that the error does not help so much?

Comment: The errors are very helpful. (1) You're using a deleted constructor io_service(io_service&). (2) the constructor was deleted because the definition would be ill-formed. (3) io_service(io_service&) is private due to being explicitly noncopyable.

Comment: From there, just look for places where your code is (wrongly) using that copy constructor.

Comment: You are right, but first error message tells me to look at `socket_(api_)`

Comment: @AdrianMunteanu: The error is just pointing to the constructor definition as a whole. You can try whether clang would do a better job in this regard. It often does.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I'd guess that the compiler is treating all the member initialisers as a single line, and the error occurs somewhere before the end of that line.

Answer (score -2):

Check your selected C++ standard are equals. On debug mode and release mode. Maybe the type, function or namespace aren't implemented or exist on the selected C++ standard.

In my case I had de following errors (Examples):

• ‘std::literals’ has not been declared

```
using namespace std::literals::string_literals;
```

• “Use of deleted function” error with std::random_device{}

```
std::random_device device = std::random_device{}
```

In my case

• Debug mode -std=c++17
• Release mode -std=c++14 (Errors due to the absence of functions, types or name spaces in C++14/ you need C++ 17.) Tons of errors.

Release mode changed to C++17. All OK, 0 errors 0 warnings.

It is not mandatory to select the 2017 c ++ standard, you must choose the one of your preference or necessary standard that have implemented all functions that you need for your project.

**Update**
Tested on Clion Windows 2018.3 with remote Linux compile.

Using -std=c++11
[image: Using -std=c++11]

Using -std=c++17
[image: Using -std=c++17]

C++ is an evolving standard: after 2003 there were 2011 (C ++ 11), then 2014 (C ++ 14) and now we have 2017 (C ++ 17) and we are working for 2020 (C ++ 20) . Many things are changing, they are deprecated, other features are new. If you want the latest update, you should use the most recent standard, if your software has code that may be deprecated then you have to use the standard with which it was created.